# Tastypie for MongoDB error: get_resource_uri() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have added tastypie to my Django project with a Mongodb backend.  When I query /api/myresource

I get this error:

```
{"error_message": "get_resource_uri() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)", 
"traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 195,
 in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 426,
 in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)
 File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 458,
 in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", 
line 1269, in get_list
paginator = self._meta.paginator_class(request.GET,
sorted_objects, resource_uri=self.get_resource_uri(), limit=self._meta.limit, max_limit=self._meta.max_limit, collection_name=self._meta.collection_name)
TypeError: get_resource_uri() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)\n"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same error when I upgraded my app from django 1.4 to 1.7 and upgraded django-tastypie too. One of my resources had it's own definition of get_resource_uri: `get_resource_uri(self, bundle_or_obj)`.

In newer versions of django-tastypie the second argument is now defaulted:

`def get_resource_uri(self, bundle_or_obj=None, url_name='api_dispatch_list'):`

So I changed my method signature to match the newer signature and all was well.

It turns out I no longer needed to override the get_resource_uri() for my use case so I could just delete it.